# How to download STANDARD-XML metadata from RETS using PHRETS

Tags: php, rets, phrets, mls

Is there any solution to download STANDARD-XML metadata from RETS using [PHRETS](https://github.com/troydavisson/PHRETS)?

Currently am able to extract each class metadata as an array using PHRETS function [GetMetadataTable](https://github.com/troydavisson/PHRETS/wiki/GetMetadataTable) and combining & converting to XML format.

But then recently I found difference in single STANDARD-XML metadata(of entire resources and classes) and individual class metadata. Using metadata viewer service [RETSMD.com](http://www.retsmd.com/)(built on PHRETS) also, the class name getting from STANDARD-XML metadata is different and unable to view the details.

Note: I got the STANDARD-XML metadata via direct browser log-in using credentials, like this
http://rets.login.url/GetMetadata?Type=METADATA-TABLE&Format=STANDARD-XML&ID=0

Anyone faced the same? Is there any solution using PHP?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I understand that, it's an old post but I'm wondering if you got your issue resolved

Comment: @Kamamba, yes I got the solution, posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution by modifying PHRETS library.
Added a new function there with following code,

```
    if (empty($this->capability_url['GetMetadata'])) {
        die("GetServerInformation() called but unable to find GetMetadata location. Failed login?\n");
    }

    $optional_params['Type']   = 'METADATA-SYSTEM';
    $optional_params['ID']     = '*';
    $optional_params['Format'] = 'STANDARD-XML';

    //request server information
    $result = $this->RETSRequest($this->capability_url['GetMetadata'], $optional_params );

    if (!$result) {
        return false;
    }
    list($headers, $body) = $result;
    $xml = $this->ParseXMLResponse($body);
```

Note: Main thing to note is,

```
$optional_params['ID']     = '*';
```

Should be '*' instead '0'

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still unable to retrieve STANDARD-XML data from the CREA DDF data feed using PhRETS v2.x.x, I created a fork to the ./src/Parsers/Search/OneX.php file.  You can add the following protected methods to the end of the file:

```
    protected function parseDDFStandardXMLData(&$xml)
    {
        // we can only work with an array
        $property_details = json_decode(json_encode($xml), true);
        $retn = array();
        if(! empty($property_details['RETS-RESPONSE']['PropertyDetails'])) {
            foreach($property_details['RETS-RESPONSE']['PropertyDetails'] as $property_array) {
                $retn[] = $this->parseArrayElements(null, $property_array);
            }
        }

        return $retn;
    }

    protected function parseArrayElements($parent_key, $element)
    {
        // three possible $element types
        //  1. scalar value
        //  2. sub-array
        //  3. SimpleXMLElement Object

        $retn = array();
        if(is_object($element)) {
            $element = json_decode(json_encode($element), true);
        }

        if(is_array($element)) {
            foreach($element as $node_key => $node) {
                $key = $node_key;
                if(! empty($parent_key)) {
                    $key = $parent_key . '|' . $key;
                }

                if(is_array($node) || is_object($node)) {
                    $nodes = $this->parseArrayElements($key, $node);
                    if(!empty($nodes)) {
                        foreach($nodes as $k => $n) {
                            $retn[$k] = $n;
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    $retn[$key] = $node;
                }
            }
        }else{
            $retn[$parent_key] = $element;
        }

        return $retn;
    }

    protected function parseRecordFromArray(&$array, Results $rs)
    {
        $r = new Record;
        foreach($rs->getHeaders() as $key => $name) {
            $r->set($name, $array[$name]);
        }
        return $r;
    }
```

Then replace the parseRecords() method with:

```
    protected function parseRecords(Session $rets, &$xml, $parameters, Results $rs)
    {
        if (isset($xml->DATA)) {
            foreach ($xml->DATA as $line) {
                $rs->addRecord($this->parseRecordFromLine($rets, $xml, $parameters, $line, $rs));
            }
        }elseif (isset($xml->{"RETS-RESPONSE"}->PropertyDetails)) {
            $data = $this->parseDDFStandardXMLData($xml);
            if(! empty($data)) {
                $fields_saved = false;
                foreach ($data as $line) {
                    if(!$fields_saved) {
                        $rs->setHeaders(array_keys($line));
                    }
                    $rs->addRecord($this->parseRecordFromArray($line, $rs));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The line, `}elseif (isset($xml->{"RETS-RESPONSE"}->PropertyDetails)) {` in the latter method does the trick to identify the STANDARD-XML RETS-RESPONSE node and parse the data.

Hope this helps,

Cheers!